# What is the '_idx' suffix for on KEY for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tried searching for this but couldn't find anything that helped me understand.

In CodeIgniter's Session table creation query for example, there's a line:

```
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
```

that comes after defining the column 'last_activity'.

What's this for?

Comment: It's a naming convention for indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the column `last_activity` is indexed, and the name of the index is `last_activity_idx`. An index means that running conditional queries based on that field will be faster.

For example, if you run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `session_table` WHERE `last_activity` = 1000
```

If the column is not indexed, MySQL will have to search through every row to check the value of that column. If that column is indexed, MySQL is able to more quickly find rows which match that column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for the clear answer! So does that mean it's worth adding an index to every column that you're likely to be searching through a lot?

Comment: @twistedpixel it's a bit more complex than that, but that is a good basic rule of thumb. You should also consider how many unique values there are for that column. If there are a lot of possible unique values, then an index is good. If there are only 3 for example, an index isn't much help, because it will only take ~1/3 of the time of a non-indexed query.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. Thanks again.